# How can I import all packages in jruby?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

In java you can do something like this, to include all packages under java namespace.

```
import java.*;
```

At https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby
They suggest using `include_package` or `import`. I also tried `java_package` and `java_import`. Is there a way to import like this or do you just require the pacakges that you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
require 'java'

module JavaUtil
  include_package "java.util"
end

JavaUtil::Date.new
```

Comment: This only works inside a module declaration to import into a module's namespace.  You cannot use `include_package` to load classes into the global namespace, so it's not really the same as "import java.*;"