# Can I use wildcards in my "java_import" statements to load into the global namespace?

Tags: jruby

> Note: **This is *not* a dupe question!**  The suggested dupe's answer only works in a module, not the global namespace, so it's not quite the same.

I'm surprised that I can't find a solid answer to this question.

**Note that `include_package` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699949/how-can-i-import-all-packages-in-jruby) is *not* the solution I am looking for, as it will only let you import a package into a *module's* namespace.  It does not load into the *global* namespace.**

If my JRuby script has something like:

```
java_import "com.example.shapes.circle"
java_import "com.example.shapes.square"
java_import "com.example.shapes.triangle"
```

I want to do something like this:

```
java_import "com.example.shapes.*"
```

But that's a syntax error, as it appears to try to load "`*`" as a literal classname and not as a wildcard.

**This also doesn't work:**

```
java_import "com.example.shapes"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm trying it, but it's not working for me.  Still investigating.

Comment: That question is not the same, because `import_package` only works within a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer appears to be "no".  You can't load all of a package's classes into the global namespace.  At least, not easily.

[A post here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/216629) appears to describe a way, though it is incredibly ugly.  (I got that link from the [JRuby Github wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby)).

That ugly way looks something like this, but it did not work for me.

```
module M
  include_package "com.example.shapes"
end

class Object
  class << self
    alias :const_missing_old :const_missing
    def const_missing c
      M.const_get c
    end
  end
end

Circle #should work
Triangle #should work
```

Again, it didn't work for me, but I might have messed something up.  I'm not going to pursue, because I'm not really interested in putting crazy hacks like this in my code.